# how update post meta when post type post edit and save

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

hi all here is my function

```
function save_urun_meta_price( $post_id ) {

    $slug = 'urun';
    if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }

    // - Update the post's metadata.

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['urun_indirimli_fiyat'] ) ) {
        $product_price = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'urun_fiyat', true );
        $product_discount = of_get_option('urun_discount');

            $yuzde =  ($product_discount / 100)*$product_price;
            $discounted = $product_price-$yuzde;

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'urun_indirimli_fiyat', $discounted  );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_urun_meta_price' );
add_action( 'edit_post', 'save_urun_meta_price' );
```

When user write some price into the **urun_fiyat** meta field i want to calculate this price with % discount field from the options framework panel.

Than i want to put new price another meta field **urun_indirimli_fiyat**..

What is wrong with my function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code. I think the problem was with the product price variable. You were trying to get the value from post meta ( which does not exist )

Getting the value from $_POST variable will do the trick I guess.

```
function save_urun_meta_price( $post_id ) {

    $slug = 'urun';
    if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }

    // - Update the post's metadata.

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['urun_indirimli_fiyat'] ) ) {
        $product_price = $_POST['urun_fiyat'];
        $product_discount = of_get_option('urun_discount');

            $yuzde =  ($product_discount / 100)*$product_price;
            $discounted = $product_price-$yuzde;

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'urun_indirimli_fiyat', $discounted  );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_urun_meta_price' );
add_action( 'edit_post', 'save_urun_meta_price' );
```

Comment: @fatih-toprak does this solve your problem ? If yes then I`ll appreciate your upvote :)